# Taking JSON output into table format

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to take the values I have parsed from a JSON file and convert them into rows.  I have tried all week, but still cannot figure this out.

---

My current output looks like this:

```
a: 1
b: 2
c: 3
a: 1a
b: 2a
c: 3a
a: 1b
b: 2b
c: 3b
```

I want my output to be like this, but I cannot find a solution.

```
a   b   c 
1   2   3
1a  2a  3a
1b  2g  3b
```

---

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = 
        @"{
            'somethingone': 'abc',
            'somethingtwo': 'abcde-1234',
            'information': 
            {
                'report': [
                     {
                        'a': '1',
                        'b': '2',
                        'c': '3'
                     },
                     {
                        'a': '1a',
                        'b': '2a',
                        'c': '3a'
                     },
                     {
                        'a': '1b',
                        'b': '2b',
                        'c': '3b'
                     },
                 ]
             }
        }";

        RootObj mainObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObj>(json);

        Console.WriteLine("somethingone: " + mainObj.somethingone);
        Console.WriteLine("somethingtwo: " + mainObj.somethingtwo);

        foreach (Dictionary<string, string> report in mainObj.information.report)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in report)
            {
                string key = item.Key;
                string value = item.Value;

                Console.WriteLine(key + ": " + value);
            }
        }
    }
}

class RootObj
{
    public string somethingone { get; set; }
    public string somethingtwo { get; set; }
    public Information information { get; set; }
}

class Information
{
    public Dictionary<string, string>[] report { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is this to output to the `console`? Or to something else? Because you're using `console.WriteLine()`, you're going to get one entry per one line. If you want multiple values per line, you should build up a string variable for each line, and then write it out when it's done

Answer (score 1):

You're writing out the key-value pairs for each dictionary one pair per line.

What you want to do instead is first write out a line containing the keys from the first dictionary, then write out one line for each dictionary containing its values.

You can use `Write` instead of `WriteLine` to write each value without a line break.  Then at the end of the line, use `WriteLine` to add the line break.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
Dictionary<string, string> firstDict = mainObj.information.report.FirstOrDefault();
if (firstDict != null)
{
    string format = "{0,-4} ";  // change the negative number to change the column width

    // write out the headers by getting the keys from the first dictionary
    foreach (string key in firstDict.Keys)
    {
        Console.Write(string.Format(format, key));
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

    // now write out the values for each dictionary
    foreach (Dictionary<string, string> dict in mainObj.information.report)
    {
        foreach (string value in dict.Values)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format(format, value));
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Note: the code above assumes that each dictionary in the report will have the same set of keys.  If this is not true, then you will need to make some adjustments to the code to handle the irregularities.

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9T9vBV

Comment: is there any way to isolate the foreach loop so that I can do the following? foreach(item in Values) {item.a, item.b, item.c}?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "isolate the foreach loop".  If the property names for `a`, `b` and `c` are always the same in the JSON (i.e. you know what they will be ahead of time) then you could use a regular class to represent the item and then you can refer the the properties like `item.a`, `item.b`, etc.  But if the names in the JSON are not always the same, then no, it wouldn't be possible to do it like that, because you wouldn't know what names to use in your code!  That is why a dictionary is useful--you don't need to know the names in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your json to table format with only one line of code than can convert your parsed json to `DataTable`  directly like

```
DataTable dt = jToken["information"]["report"].ToObject<DataTable>();
```

So you can take advantage of `JToken` and `DataTable` together to deserialize your json to directly into table like

```
JToken jToken = JToken.Parse(json);

DataTable dt = jToken["information"]["report"].ToObject<DataTable>();

Console.WriteLine("a \t b \t c");
Console.WriteLine("-------------------");

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
     Console.WriteLine($"{dr["a"]} \t {dr["b"]} \t {dr["c"]}");
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output:**

[image]

## Live Demo

Comment: This is my third answer to you. I hope you can reply me to know whether it help you or not. :)